# "Cannot resolve symbol" on soap12:binding

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I'm configuring an WSDL file. I'm using java 7, IntelliJ 2019.2 and SoapUi To test my request.
I'm using soap12 to help. Into the Binding section, I have `<soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>`
However, I have a "cannot resolve symbol" on the binding. I do have the same for `<soap12:operation soapAction="" />`and `<soap12:body use="literal" />`

I have tried to modify my WSDL definition which now looks like this :

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:tns="http://*******.******.**/*****/****" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
               name="***********" targetNamespace="http://*******.****.**/*****/****">
```

I'm working with IntelliJ, I've tried to reimport, to regenerate sources & update folders, to modify the WSDL definition. But none of this works.

This is a little part of my binding part, but it looks the same for all the others :

```
    <wsdl:binding name="***********" type="tns:***********" >
    <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

    <wsdl:operation name="demandeNumeroOuValidation">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input name="demandeNumeroOuValidationRequest">
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="demandeNumeroOuValidationResponse">
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
```

I do know if something is not imported well. It throws no error. When I launch SoapUI, it says "Got response" but nothing is returned.

The "cannot resolve symbol" on the soap12:method seems to not allow me to get a response.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. IntelliJ highlights in red "Cannot resolve symbol 'soap12: binding'" without a suggested fix and the rest of the wsdl file looks correct. Then I run "mvn generate-sources" in a terminal and the classes are (seems) generated correctly. I think IntelliJ highlights in red but he doesn't know why, neither do I and in any case it doesn't seem to bother maven to generate the classes.